# Multiplication of values in a dataframe with scalars

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a problem where I want to convert X and Y pixel values to physical coordinates. I have a huge folder containing many csv files and i load them, pass them to my function, compute the coordinates and overwrite the columns and return the data frame. I then overwrite it outside the function. I have the formula which does it correctly but I am having some problems implementing it in python.

Each CSV files has many columns. The columns I am interested in are Latitude (degree), Longitude (degree), XPOS and YPOS. The former 2 are blank and the latter 2 have the data with which I need to fill up the former two.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

max_long = float(XXXX)
max_lat = float(XXXX)
min_long = float(XXXX)
min_lat = float(XXXX)
hoi = int(909)
woi = int(1070)

def pixel2coor (filepath, max_long, max_lat, min_lat, min_long, hoi, woi):
    data = pd.read_csv(filepath) #reading Csv
    data2 = data.set_index("Log File") #Setting index of dataframe with first column
    data2.loc[data2['Longitude (degree)']] = (((max_long-min_long)/hoi)*[data2[:,'XPOS']]+min_long) #Computing Longitude & Overwriting
    data2.loc[data2['Latitude (degree)']] = (((max_lat-min_lat)/woi)*[data2[:,'YPOS']]+min_lat) #Computing Latitude & Overwriting
    return data2 #Return dataframe


filenames = sorted(glob.glob('*.csv')) 

for file in filenames: 
    df = pixel2coor (file, max_long, max_lat, min_lat, min_long, hoi, woi) #Calling pixel 2 coor function and passing a csv file in every iteration
    df.to_csv(file) #overwriting the file with the dataframe
```

I am getting the following error.

**

> TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 'XPOS')' is an invalid key

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your syntax is off. In the following line:

```
data2.loc[data2['Longitude (degree)']] = (((max_long-min_long)/hoi)*[data2[:,'XPOS']]+min_long) #Computing Longitude & Overwriting
```

The left side of your equation appears to be referring to a column, but you have it in the 'row' section of .loc slicer. So it should be:

```
data2.loc[:, 'Longitude (degree)']
```

On the right side of your equation, you've forgotten .loc or need to drop the ':,'  so two possible solutions:

```
(((max_long-min_long)/hoi)*data2.loc[:,'XPOS']+min_long)

(((max_long-min_long)/hoi)*data2['XPOS']+min_long)
```

Also, I would add that your brackets on the right side should be more explicit. It's a bit unclear how you want scalars to act on the series. Do you want to add min_long first? Or multiply (((max_long-min_long)/hoi) first?

Your final row might look like this, forcing addition first as an example:

```
data2.loc[:, 'Longitude (degree)'] = ((max_long-min_long)/hoi)*(data2.loc[:,'XPOS']+min_long)
```

This applies to your next line as well. You may get more errors after you fix this.